# error handling with array of promises fails to return custom errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, promise

I'm calling an async function which returns an array of promises to deal with the fact that eslint won't let you use await in a for loop...

my function is passing strings from an array one by one into another function which is doing some encoding and then waiting for them all to finish before returning the final encoded values as you can imagine a few things screw up on the encoding side and that module will throw relevant errors as needed

my issue is that unfortunately, when returning an array of promises those errors will not show on the stack trace... the only error that I get back is a generic 500 server error but none of my custom errors show

```
async function decodedAddresses(req, addresses) {
  if (!Array.isArray(addresses)) {
    return decodeId(req, addressId, idType.address);
  }

  return Promise.all(
    addresses.map(id => {
      return decoded(req, id).then(addr => {
        return {
          address: addr,
        };
      });
    })
  ).
  });
}
```

however if I simply call my function and have it return this way without the array of promises I have no issues and all the errors appear on the stack trace

```
async function decodedAddresses(req, addresses) {
return decoded(req, id)
}
```

also the length of the addresses does not matter it can be an array[1] or array[2] etc... the same issue occurs, I'm hoping someone might have some insight into why an array of promises may somehow be overwriting or not placing these errors on the stack

Comment: `Promise.all()` rejects immediately when any of the promises is rejected. So you can't get all the errors, just the first error.

Comment: "... to deal with the fact that eslint won't let you use await in a for loop". You cannot await but you can use promises inside a for loop. Here more info and useful examples: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop

Comment: Use [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) to wait for all the promises to be resolved or rejected. Then you can get all the rejection details, as well as all the successful results.

Comment: allSettled should do the work. As an alternative, you might just do a `decoded(req, id).then(...).catch(e => e)` inside the map and later you may check the `instanceof Error`.